# How to show a minimized application in the Running Apps bar in Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm a beginner so sorry if my question seems basic.
I've looked online but haven't find anything on it so it must be something very simple.

I'm trying to get my application to show in the running apps bar in windows mobile when minimized.
I minimize the app using  ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_MINIMIZED); and it works fine but my app does not appear neither in the running apps, nor in the settings\memory\running programs.
When i click the app icon in the start menu, it shows me the last status of the app so i conclude it is indeed minimized and not closed.
I've also set the icon in the form to the app icon, to no avail.

Is there sometinhg i'm missing?
BTW, i'm using CF3.5 with Winmo 6 pro.
Thank you
Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Running Programs" applets simply enumerates the Form Text of all top-level windows (it's not looking at processes).  Make sure your Form has the Text property set and it will appear.

Comment: sorry, discard my last (dumb) question...
it works now.
thank you.